# Debugging error org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection or outbound has closed, the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, netbeans, apache-axis

We are facing trouble trying to connect to a web service using Netbeans with Java OpenJDK 14 and Apache Tomcat 9. It's a specific environment which requires Axis2 1.6.2 library to connect to WSDL via SSL certificate trusted with keytool. We changed Axis2 to 1.7.9 without success.

We get the following error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection or outbound has closed
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:78)
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:84)

com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Connection or outbound has closed
    com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1687)
    com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.close(BaseStreamWriter.java:288)
    org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.close(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:222)
    org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:192)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:84)

java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1246)
    java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:153)
```

We tried to test a java main class with the following code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "pathToKeystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "myKeystorePassword");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");

RPCServiceClient serviceClient = new RPCServiceClient();
Options options = serviceClient.getOptions();

EndpointReference targetEPR = new EndpointReference(wsdlDatos);
options.setTo(targetEPR);
options.setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(600000);

clientDatosConsultaDetalles datos = new clientDatosConsultaDetalles();

datos.setUser(usuario);
datos.setPassword(password);
datos.setIpAddress(ip);


System.out.println("Getting service: " + wsdlDatos);
System.out.println(targetEPR.getAddress()); 

// Generate curp
QName service = new QName("http://services.wserv.ecurp.dgti.segob.gob.mx", "consultarCurpDetalle");

Object[] serviceArgs = new Object[]{datos};

Class[] returnTypes = new Class[]{String.class};

Object[] response = serviceClient.invokeBlocking(service, serviceArgs, returnTypes);
```

However, the line which throws error is the last one:

```
Object[] response = serviceClient.invokeBlocking(service, serviceArgs, returnTypes);
```

Firewall rules are open and the web service allows connection to a list of IP Addresses. Our IP is allowed to connect so any ideas on how can we debug this error please? We think the connection to the web service is being rejected but we are not sure.

EDIT: After following suggestion from comment, it turned out it may be a problem with SSL certificate, since using jvm parameter

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

revealed the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

We are using keytool with OpenJDK 14 as follows:

```
keytool -import -alias inea -keystore c:\WSCURP\2021\ineacurp.keystore -trustcacerts -file theCer.cer
```

The keystore is generated automatically with the line above. An organization for finding people info provides us the .cer file. Probably we are missing some crucial step in importing the .cer file.

The keystore file contents are being displayed in the debugger, which means that keystore is being detected and there's read/write permissions on the file.

It's curious that the responder_id is empty, according to the debugger

```
"status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
```

Any additional suggestions?

Comment: If I had to guess the SSL handshake failed. Run the test code with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` or `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to see where the connection fails.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz with using -Djavax.net.debug=all as a jvm parameter, an underlying error was detected. `Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty` I provided further details in the post, any additional suggestions?

Comment: It is not clear from your edited message: does the SSL handshake succeed? Do you get all the messages from `Produced ClientHello handshake message` to `Consuming server Finished handshake message`? You can refine the logged data with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` and add it to the question?

Comment: Well, actually it was a silly mistake. As it is an imported project, Netbeans didn't recognized all of the libraries in the lib folder, I don't know why. However, the following library was missing: `javaee-endorsed-api-6.0`. Project didn't complain on compilation neither runtime. I was expecting the build to fail due to missing library. After adding it, it worked like charm. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It was a silly mistake in this case. I was expecting Netbeans to recognize all of the contents in the lib folder, as it's an imported Web project. However, it didn't happen. Netbeans asked to solve missing dependencies but not all of them were detected. The missing library was javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.

The project didn't complain on compilation neither runtime, but handshake was unable to communicate. This may serve as an alternative for the axis2 error which I see is not very common when googling it.